# Diffrent CSS-Styles for Facebook Iframe

Tags: css, facebook, iframe

Anyone who has a good idea, how to add additional styles to an facebook iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with CSS you can add link to an external sheet on each tab

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question about [applying css to an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe).  If the iframe content is on a different domain, like what happens in the case of Facebook iFrame content on your site, you have no control over it due to cross site restrictions.  Some older Facebook plugins allow to you specify a stylesheet on your server that they download and import to their server, but most of their newer plugins to not allow for this.  Also, their terms of service often state you cannot attempt to the modify their iframe content embeded on your site.